# C# with MySQL through Connector/NET

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm developing CMS application in C#(4.0 Framework) which connects to MySQL database (5.0.95) on remote server
by MySQL Connector (6.5.4).

I have problem with executing queries.

e.g.
My connection string:

```
"Server=" + Options.DbServer + ";Database="+ Options.Database +";Uid=" + Options.DbUser + ";Pwd=" + Options.DbPassword + ";CharSet=utf8; Connect Timeout=30;";
```

I have static class which manages database related stuff, and there I have private member _connection.

```
private static MySqlConnection _connection;
public static MySqlConnection Connection
{ 
    get
    {
        if (_connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            _connection.Open();

        return _connection;
    } 
    set { _connection = value; }
}
```

This is method which initializes connection:

```
public static bool Init(string cs)
{
    _connection = new MySqlConnection(cs);
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SET NAMES utf8", Connection);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    return true;
}
```

This is method where I get exception:

```
public static bool InsertRecord(MySqlCommand command)
{
    command.Connection = Connection;
    if(command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

`command.ExecuteNonQuery()` throws exception: Fatal error encountered during command execution.

This is stack trace...

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException was unhandled
  Message=Fatal error encountered during command execution.
  Source=MySql.Data
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  Number=0
  StackTrace:
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
       at CMS.Database.InsertRecord(MySqlCommand command) in C:\_myStuff\VS2010\CMS\CMS\Database.cs:line 95
       at CMS.frmAddItem.btnDo_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\_myStuff\VS2010\CMS\CMS\frmAddItem.cs:line 138
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(Form form)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
       at CMS.frmMain.btnNovi_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\_myStuff\VS2010\CMS\CMS\frmMain.cs:line 381
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(Form form)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
       at CMS.frmLogin.DoLogin() in C:\_myStuff\VS2010\CMS\CMS\frmLogin.cs:line 55
       at CMS.frmLogin.button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\_myStuff\VS2010\CMS\CMS\frmLogin.cs:line 31
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at CMS.Program.Main() in C:\_myStuff\VS2010\CMS\CMS\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
       Message=Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset.
       Source=MySql.Data
       ErrorCode=-2147467259
       Number=0
       StackTrace:
            at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
            at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
       InnerException: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
            Message=Reading from the stream has failed.
            Source=MySql.Data
            ErrorCode=-2147467259
            Number=0
            StackTrace:
                 at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
                 at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
                 at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int32& insertedId)
                 at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int32& insertedId)
                 at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
                 at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
            InnerException: System.IO.EndOfStreamException
                 Message=Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
                 Source=MySql.Data
                 StackTrace:
                      at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
                      at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
                 InnerException:
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `Message=Attempted to read past the end of the stream.` - You are executing a _reader_ somewhere.

Comment: The stacktrace indicates that ExecuteNonQuery calls ExecuteReader. I'd say you're still not connecting successfully to the database. Do you ever get to call `Init()` ?

Comment: What is `command` at the point where you get the exception? Take a look there. Breakpoints are useful to examine state before the exception occurs...

Comment: @Oded:
No, I'm not executing reader. It is like dwerner says, reader is called indirectly, by ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: @dwerner:
I'm connected to database. To be more specific, my query sometimes finish with success. Exception is thrown after a period of inactivity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I notice that you open connections, but you don't close them when you are done with them. I prefer the approach of opening connections when they are needed, rather than possibly opening them if they are not already open. They may be stale.

Cache the *connection string* but not the connection itself.

```
public static string ConnectionString {get;set;}

public static bool InsertRecord(sql)
{
    bool success = false;
    using (var con = new Connection(ConnectionString)){
        var command = new SqlCommand(sql,con);
        success = (command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0);
    }
    return success;
}
```

Resources should be freed when they are no longer required.

Comment: Yes, this is obviously better approach. I changed my methods according to your suggestion, and exceptions are gone. For now. :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you check [this](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=48494) bug report regarding this issue.

Comment: @Mikhail Preyskurantov:
Thank you for your suggestion, but in example you are directing me to, guy has in some of Inner exceptions message: `"Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation
or the server is not responding."`
I don't have that message in my stack trace.
Finally, I added command timeout in my connection string, but situation is still same.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL uses a bunch of different timeout variables at different levels.

When connection is being established -> **connect_timeout**

When server waits idle for another query to be sent -> **wait_timeout**

If query is being read or result set is being sent back -> **net_read_timeout** and **net_write_timeout**

Both net_write_timeout and net_read_timeout are session level variables, so you could simply change them per connections when you know that the query will be troublesome and therefore it will not be affecting the rest of the server. (as a workaround)

But first, you should checks the default value for each of these timeout values on your server by executing something like :

```
show variables like '%timeout%'
```

You should also look at the command you're inserting and see if it can be simplified, or broken down intro smaller updates.

Comment: These are my values:
net_read_timeout 30
net_write_timeout 60
So, it means that read timeout is 30 seconds?
My query is in fact very simple, I'm inserting record in table with 4 columns.

Comment: yes, it seems so ^^
Does it match with the time it takes to crash ?
try 'SET @@session.net_read_timeout=360;' before the insert query if that's the case.

Comment: No, it crashes almost immediately, so I don't think increasing this timeout will help.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `MySqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 600` worked for me. Here's the link where I found it:

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/665556/Connection-Timeout-Problem-with-MySqlDataAdapter-h